# Can I command both Ghouls and Zombies/Skeletons with one bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, undead, necromancy

Let's say I play a necromancer and have raised some Skeletons or Zombies using Animate Dead and some Gouls, Ghasts, Wights or Mummies using Create Undead.

When I use a bonus action to command them can I command all the undead I have with single bonus action even though they were created with different spells?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No, you can only command the creatures created by one of the spells when you use your bonus action.

While both spells state that they require a bonus action, both of them only allow you to command creatures you made with that particular spell.

Here is the relevant rules text for *Animate Dead*:

> On each of your turns, you can use a Bonus Action to mentally Command **any creature you made with this spell** [...]

As well as the rules text for *Create Undead*:

> As a Bonus Action on each of your turns, you can mentally Command **any creature you animated with this spell** [...]

Comment: Can I command creatures created by two casts of the same spell with one bonus action?

Comment: @enumag You should ask this in a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

### No.

Both spells have this phrasing (emphasis added):

> On each of your turns, you can use a Bonus Action to mentally Command any creature **you made with this spell** if the creature is within 60 feet of you (if you control multiple creatures, you can Command any or all of them at the same time, issuing the same Command to each one)

While the parenthentical clause might make it seem like you can control everything, the first part of the sentence is clear that each use of a bonus action only applies to the creatures from a single spell, and not others. Therefore, if you have undead animated from two separate spells, you will have to control them on different turns, since you only have one bonus action per round.

Answer (score 5):

## No

The spells lists the option as follows (**emphasis** mine)

> On each of your turns, you can use a bonus action to mentally command any creature you made with **this spell**

Since you can only command creatures created by the specific spell, any other creatures are not commanded, even though the spells are related.

Answer (score 4):

The spells have the following text:

> As a Bonus Action on each of your turns, you can mentally Command any creature you animated with this spell if the creature is within 120 feet of you (if you control multiple creatures, you can Command any or all of them at the same time, issuing the same Command to each one)
>
> On each of your turns, you can use a Bonus Action to mentally Command any creature you made with this spell if the creature is within 60 feet of you (if you control multiple creatures, you can Command any or all of them at the same time, issuing the same Command to each one)

Each permit you to spend a Bonus Action to Command any creature you [created/animated] with **this spell** if **condition**.  They then let you control multiple creatures with the same command.

It is ambiguous if this Bonus Action to mentally Command is the same kind of bonus action or a different one; they are both Bonus Actions to Command creatures.  It is reasonable for them to be different kinds of Bonus Actions (qualified by spell), or the same Bonus Action (a mental Command Bonus Action), with possibly different effects.

If we go with "the same kind of bonus action, just different effects" as the plain-English reading would indicate, then, it is ambiguous if the text in () applies across spells.  If the text in () said "if you control multiple creatures animated with this spell" it would be clear, but the text in () doesn't explicitly restrict the "multiple creatures" to be ones animated/created with this spell.

Any answer either way should be treated as suspect, barring a designer weighing in.

It is even ambiguous if multiple casts of *this spell* count for the second clause or not (ie, is it *this spell* as in this instance of this spell, or *this spell* as in all castings of this spell?  Or is the bonus action granted by the first cast of *this spell* a different bonus action than the one granted by the second cast of *this spell*?  Ambiguous.)

D&D 5e is written in English prose, and lots of things are ambiguous in English prose.  You must work out what is reasonable with your DM.

It would be reasonable for your DM to read the rules as stating that one command would work only on undead created by one cast of one of those spells, or it working on all undead created by multiple castings of one of those spells, or on all undead created by any number of castings of both spells.  The text is simply not clear.

And there are game fictions reasons for any of those 3 to be supported.

Comment: I think "this spell" is pretty clear. "This spell" means "the spell currently being described". It takes a weirdly broad reading to come up with "creatures created by any spell with similar rules" (*Animate Objects* uses the same phrasing after all). If they meant "any undead created by the caster" or "any creatures requiring a bonus action to command" they could have said so, but by saying it's limited to those created by "this spell", they eliminated those options. I agree, it's weird to have the skeletons and zombies wait a bit while the ghouls charge in first, but RAW, that's how it goes.